# Custom AJAX dataType type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is such thing possible?

I want to create a dataType called "json/rows", that parses the text the server outputs, and does something to it, then it goes to the success function?

Example code in how I think it should work:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json/rows",
    dataTypeParser: function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        response.rows = "test";
        return response;
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.lo(response.rows); //console logs "test"
    }
})
```

Comment: Everything is possible. This is not default functionality but it would certainly be possible to extend the `$.ajax()` function to include it, if you feel it would be helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with using `json` as datatype? For custom datatype, you need to pass `accepts` & `converters` parameters, check doc: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks! JSON for me takes about 50MB in my specific case of dumping an entire table, while creating my own data type takes only 20MB, but requires extra work from the client's side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings):

```
$.ajax({
  accepts: {
    mycustomtype: 'application/x-some-custom-type'
  },

  // Instructions for how to deserialize a `mycustomtype`
  converters: {
    'text mycustomtype': function(result) {
      // Do Stuff
      return newresult;
    }
  },

  // Expect a `mycustomtype` back from server
  dataType: 'mycustomtype'
});
```

here use `json/rows` instead of `application/x-some-custom-type`

Comment: There is a convention to custom MIME types. `application/x-json-rows` would be more appropriate than `json/rows`.